# Line-wrapping `less` in OS X (specifically for use with 'git diff')

Tags: macos, command-line, terminal, osx-mavericks, less

Using `less +-S` does not work (although it does ask `Chop long lines  (press RETURN)`), and entering `-S` once inside `less` also does not work. Is there a solution?

I am usig [OS X Mavericks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X_Mavericks) (10.9.3).

less 418 (default) or less 458 (via [MacPorts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacPorts))

Comment: What do "less 418" and "less 458" mean? Are they version numbers? Access rights? Formatting specifications?

Comment: @PeterMortensen: They're the `less` version number as output by `less --version`. OS X still ships version 418 in Yosemite, by the way, and I see the same buggy behavior with `less -S` on Yosemite, so this question is not dead, even if it is "answered". I've seen this behavior for years and years on multiple OSes, though so my belief is that `less -S` is just plain buggy.

Comment: How about `icdiff`: https://github.com/jeffkaufman/icdiff

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `fold` to first wrap the text, then pipe to `less`:

```
fold -w 78 | less
```

Of course, `-w` sets the number of characters. By default it's 80. `fold` is POSIX and bundled with OS X.

---

[Apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136178/git-diff-handling-long-lines), using `less -r` as the default Git pager will also achieve folding of long lines.

Otherwise, while the diff is being displayed, you can type `-S`, then <kbd>Enter</kbd> to toggle chopping/folding long lines.

Comment: +1 for a cool work-around, but I'm actually hoping to use this for the (`git`) `diff` command --- so I don't think this will work

Comment: Oh, you didn't mention. Does setting `less -r` as Git pager work in that case?

Comment: Yes!  That works!  (I saw that on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/136178/git-diff-handling-long-lines) but didn't try it because my man page said `less -r` did something completely different.  Any idea why this works in git, but not terminal?

Comment: I have no idea why exactly. I just remembered this trick. I'm curious why `less -+S` doesn't work in your case. In fact, in my setup (also under OS X), the diff shown in `less` is automatically line-wrapped, but I haven't set anything explicitly to enable it.

Comment: That's very strange!  Maybe this is unique to me then.